# Selectize - select 2nd option on load

Tags: javascript, jquery, selectize.js

On load, how to select second option using selectize plugin?

https://github.com/selectize/selectize.js

As per below example, it have to select 21-Nov-2017.

I can able to select option using value.. but, this value will be dynamic and will change daily.

Thanks

**HTML:**

```
<select>
 <option value="20-Nov-2017">20-Nov-2017</option>
 <option value="21-Nov-2017">21-Nov-2017</option>
 <option value="22-Nov-2017">22-Nov-2017</option>
</select>
```

Comment: use index if you want to select second

Answer (score 1):

You can select the second value on the basis of index like this

```js
$('#selectBox :nth-child(2)').prop('selected', true);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="selectBox">
  <option value="0">Number 0</option>
  <option value="1">Number 1</option>
  <option value="2">Number 2</option>
  <option value="3">Number 3</option>
  <option value="4">Number 4</option>
  <option value="5">Number 5</option>
  <option value="6">Number 6</option>
  <option value="7">Number 7</option>
</select>
```

Comment: i want this method to render on selectize plugin

Answer (score 0):

In version 1.6 and higher the prop() method is recommended:

```
$('.selDiv option:eq(1)').prop('selected', true)
```

In older versions:

```
$('.selDiv option:eq(1)').attr('selected', 'selected')
```

Comment: yes you can use like this $('.selDiv').selectize.setValue($('.selDiv option:eq(2)').val());

Comment: I tried this method earlier boss!! but, getting "undefined" error.